# "Set global variable" or "Set Suite Variable" keywords are not functioning in Robot Framework

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, robotframework, robotframework-ide

I have keyword written in Python which is returning dictionary, I want to use that dictionary anywhere in any test case or test suite or any .robot file.

I am trying to use "set global variable", but for some reason it is not working.

I defined the "set global variable" in abc.robot file's keyword and tried to access it in the same file's test case and any other .robot file, but IDE is showing error message "Variable 'Variable name' is used, but not defined"

***main.robot***

```
**** Settings ***
Library    Module_1.py    
Library    Collections

*** Keywords ***
Set Dictionary Variable 
    ${Dictionary}    Return Dictionary
    Set Global Variable   ${Dictionary}

*** Test cases ***
Test case 1
    Set Dictionary Variable

Test case 2
    log    ${Dictionary}

Test case 3
    log    ${Dictionary}
```

***Module_1.py***

```
class Module_1:
    def Return_Dictionary(self):
        Dict = {1: 'Geeks', 2: 'For', 3: 'Geeks'} 
        return Dict
```

Would you please advise how I can make it work OR is there any other technique I can use to access the Python keyword's returned dictionary anywhere in my project?

[image]

Comment: What you are doing looks correct, but you didn't provide a [mcve]. I tried to reformat your code to make it runnable, but since you didn't define `Return Dictionary Keyword` or show how you're salling `Set Dictionary Variable keyword` it's hard for us to provide help. Are you sure that you're calling `Set Dictionary Variable Keyword` before your test cases run, and are you sure that `Return Dictionary Keyword` is actually returning a dictionary?

Comment: Please let us know if the test isn't running, or if the problem is only in the IDE. What happens when you run the test from the command line?

Comment: Thanks Bryan for your analysis and editing the source code!            I was not running the keyword of "Set Global Variable" before running the test cases. After adding the keyword of "Set Global Variable" first and then test cases has fixed the issue of accessing the "Set"Global Variable" in all test cases. However, IDE is still showing the message ""Variable 'Variable name' is used, but not defined"". It looks like RED (Eclipse IDE) issue.